# which sql query is better for bit type?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a method to get the count of usernames with the lock flag in database

```
public bool UsernameExistInDatabase(string username)
{
    bool states = false;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = '1')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();
        if (result > 0)
        {
            states = true;
        }
    }
    return states;
}
```

but I have three different ways

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = '1')
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = 1)
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = 'true')
```

which one should I choose for my code (i.e. which one is better)

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9BmB.png)
[running 3 query and same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Sko.png)

Comment: you show it as a bit, so this one: SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = 1)

Comment: They may all work (which I actually find surprising), but you should use the one that most clearly defines the type in the db.

Comment: I guess the SQL server is smart enough to optimize the query by itself. So it does not seem to make any difference. I'd personally prefer `lock = 1` as this seems more type safe than the others.

Comment: Passing `'true'` requires an internal conversion to `1`, passing `'1'` requires an internal conversion to `1`, so use `1` as the values for a `bit` are `1` or `0` (or `NULL`)

Comment: I don't do much .net stuff, but wouldn't all three fail due to the lack of an alias for `count(username)`?

Comment: I was looking at the line where the value gets passed to the variable named result.

Comment: you have to be careful with BIT implicit conversion. 0 means 0 but any other value could potentially be interpreted as 1. For example, if you convert a 2 to a bit, it becomes 1. There fore 2 could be interpreted as 1. I wonder if '0' is interpreted as 1

Comment: i normally use "  (lock = 1)  "  but which one is better  in performance?

Comment: Performance? The 2nd avoids conversion, so its guaranteed to be the fastest. Putting an index on the lock column will affect performance, because your query is SARGable

Comment: @montewhizdoh The 2nd one also requires the least amount of typing. I think we have a clear winner!

Comment: Thank you for using 'using' - warms my heart! BTW "=1" is the way to go

Comment: n8wrl, I tried this but it didnt work!!! SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock  "=1")    (heheheeh)

Comment: You can get rid of `states` variable and use `return result > 0`

Comment: @n8wrl but he is not using using using cmd which should be using using as well as con (is using).

Comment: @AlexK: I know, I know, I'm just so excited to see _something_ potentially copied-and-pasted with _some_ using

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, since there's loads of ways to indicate true, yet most DB engines reliably treat Zero as false, I generally factor true to be NOT False as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock <> 0)
```

Obviously if NULL is an issue and you expect NULL to read as false, you'd have to do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock IS NOT NULL AND lock <> 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `where lock = 1`; `'1'` and `true` both will occur an unnecessary conversion. Also, `'true'` is incorrect.

### bit

> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.

**remarks**

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Src : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx

Comment: 'true' is fine unquoted TRUE is not

Answer (score 0):

You should always make it clear to the next person who has to deal with your code what your intentions are. In this case your column is a non null-able bit column, which has the potential values 0 or 1 (ignoring any conversions).

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE lock = 1
```

Is your best way here - no strange internal conversions and no confusion about what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest =1 and I can't resist rewriting your method to use using all the way...

```
public bool UsernameExistInDatabase(string username)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM tbl_sample WHERE (lock = 1)";
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (result > 0)
            {
                // No worries about con.Close()! Using will handle it
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have to say the method name itself confuses me - we're clearly looking for whether a user exists in the database *and* is locked? Are we saying the user exists in the DB as the method name suggests?